# Why is my data frame empty even after I append all the article titles to the list and convert the list to a DF?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, web-scraping, python-newspaper

I am trying to scrape off titles of news articles from the newspaper website Khaleej times (https://www.khaleejtimes.com) and store them in a CSV file

The order is as follows:
I scrape them (theoretically), 
 Print them out (redundant and a waste of time, I know),
 Append them to a list,
 Print out the list (just to check if the list actually has anything),
 Conver the list to a Pandas Data Frame,
 and finally, convert the Data Frame to a CSV file

However, every time I run the code, nothing gets appended to the list thus leaving my DataFrame and CSV file empty. Sometimes one or two article titles appear, but most of the time it is empty.

Note: My only interest is article titles, and not the text

I've got more questions about this task, but I'll save them for a separate post

The one thing I did try was to remove HTTPS from the URL and make it HTTP as well as getting rid of www. That didn't really do much if anything at all

```
from newspaper import Article
import newspaper
import csv
import pandas as pd
url = 'http://khaleejtimes.com'

a = newspaper.build(url)

titles = []  # initialize an empty list of titles

for article in a.articles:
    article.download()  # download the article
    article.parse()  # parse the article
    # print(article.title) print the title
    titles.append(article.title)  # append the title to the list


for i in range(len(titles)):  # initialize a for loop 
    print(titles[i])  # to print the titles within the titles list

TitleDF = pd.DataFrame({'Title': titles})  # convert the titles list to a 
pandas DataFrame
print(TitleDF)  # print the DataFrame
TitleDF.to_csv('KhaleejArticles.csv', encoding='utf-8', sep="\n")  
# Convert the DataFrame to csv format
```

I expect the output of print(TitleDF) to be two columns: one with the indices (0, 1, 2... n) and Titles (article titles exclusively).

However, on several occasions, it was either several titles repeated, very few titles, and for the most no titles at all.

What am I doing wrong? This is not a syntax error as far as I can tell

Comment: there's no syntax error that I can see. When I ran and debug your code, it seems to have only returned 1 article in `a`. So might be something with the website, or how `newspaper` works under the hood to pull out those articles.

Comment: Could it have something to do with scraping rate limits on websites? I tried changing the website to Wikipedia and then CNN, the outcome was the same (well, it actually threw an error 403 for CNN and did nothing at all for Wikipedia). I changed the user agent and that didn't help either, it went back to producing an empty CSV file.

Comment: Hard to say. I’m just not familiar with how the newspaper package works. The page may be dynamic in that it’s not all rendered at the initial request so it doesn’t get all the data.